# Restrict image inside FrameLayout so it can't be dragged outside of it in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm using `FrameLayout` having shadow inside layout. On Top of `FrameLayout`, I've added `ImageView` which is draggable around the screen & Resizable.

I've given `FrameLayout` : `android:layout_width` & `android:layout_height`to `fill_parent` to consume the area of screen. It was necessary to fulfil the app requirement.

### Question

How can I restrict `Image` not to be draggable outside the`FrameLayout`?

Pic 1 and Pic 2:

[image: Image 1] [image: Image 3]

Pic 3:

[image: Image 2]

Comment: How are you making it draggable?

Comment: @kabuko : I'm using `Matrix` on `ImageView`and adding `onTouchListener` to it. But My OP is Very different from your comment

Comment: It's actually very relevant. If you could include your code for that it'd be easier to help you, but basically the approach would be to not *always* drag, but only do so within certain bounds. You'd check in `onTouch` whether `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` are within an acceptable range (i.e. the bounds of your FrameLayout, maybe +/- the half the width/height of your image).

Comment: @kabuko : thanks for pointing in to very direction which i need to be. But how can i bound `event.get()` up to `FrameLayout` region??

Comment: @kabuko: getting size of `FrameLayout` and restricting seems difficult as retrieving size of `ImageView` is as same as `FrameLayout`. Is there any way to go through it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding limitation to draggable views with reference to its size and touch points had fix my problem.

So What i need to do is just get the ***touch points*** compare it with `framelayout` boundraies, depends upon the scenario sets the limitation to draggable view.

Code is something like these worked perferctly for me ::

```
public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent event)
    {
      ImageView view = (ImageView)paramView;
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)


case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

          if (mode == DRAG) {
/*
* Restricting Image not to be draggable outside of FrameLayout
*/
              matrix.set(savedMatrix); //Top
              if(event.getY()==0)
              {
                  matrix.postTranslate(event.getX()+15-start.x, 0+15);
                  Log.d("Top", "Top...");
              }
              else if(event.getX()==0) //Left
              {
                  matrix.postTranslate(0+15, event.getY()-start.y+15);
                  Log.d("LEFT", "Left...");
              }
              else if((event.getY()-ImageHeight)>fm.getHeight()) //Bottom
              {
                  matrix.postTranslate(event.getX()-start.x+15, fm.getHeight()-ImageHeight+15);
                  Log.d("BOTTOM", "Bottom...");
              }
              else if((event.getX()-ImageWidth)>fm.getWidth()) //Right
              {
                  matrix.postTranslate(fm.getWidth()-ImageWidth+15, event.getY()-start.y+15);
                  Log.d("RIGHT", "Right....");
              }
              else if(event.getY()==0 && (event.getX()-ImageWidth)>fm.getWidth()) //Top -Right
              {
                  matrix.postTranslate(fm.getWidth()-ImageWidth-15, 15);
              }
              else if(event.getY()==0 &&event.getX()==0) //Top-Left
              {
                  matrix.postTranslate(15, 15);
              }
              else if((event.getY()-ImageHeight)>fm.getHeight() && event.getX()==0) //Bottom-Left
              {
                  matrix.postTranslate(15, fm.getHeight()-ImageHeight-15);
              }
              else if((event.getX()-ImageWidth)>fm.getWidth() && (event.getY()-ImageHeight)>fm.getHeight())
              {
                  matrix.postTranslate(fm.getWidth()-ImageWidth-15, fm.getHeight()-ImageHeight-15);
              }
              else
              {
                  matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);  
                  Log.d("ACTION_MOVE", "Starting Point::"+start.x+","+start.y+" Ending Point::"+event.getX()+","+event.getY());
                  Log.d("ACTION_DOWN", "FrameLayout::"+fm.getWidth()+" ,"+fm.getHeight()+" ImageView:: "+view.getWidth()+", "+view.getHeight());

              }
          }
          else if (mode == ZOOM) {

              float newDist = spacing(event);
              Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
              if (newDist > 10f) {

                  matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                  float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                  matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
              }
          }
          break;
           }  
      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
      return true;       
    }
```

Comment: @Vikalp Patel also have a look at my question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999891/bound-a-view-to-drag-inside-relativelayout