# Bound a View to drag inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ontouchlistener, android-relativelayout

> I have created a **draggable view inside RelativeLayout**. But it seems to go beyond the RelativeLayout.

**I simply want to make a View draggable inside ViewGroup**

And this view is `draggable` according to Screen. And it is draggable beyond the boundaries of RelativeLayout. How could I restrict it to stay draggable within RelativeLayout.

**CustomImageButton**

```
public class ImageButtonCustom extends ImageButton implements View.OnTouchListener{

    float dX, dY;

    private RelativeLayout rootView;
    private ImageButtonCustom imageButtonCustom;
    private OnMoveListener onMoveListener;

    public ImageButtonCustom(Context context,RelativeLayout rootView){
        super(context);
        this.rootView = rootView;
        init();

    }
    public ImageButtonCustom(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ImageButtonCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ImageButtonCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        imageButtonCustom = this;
        setImageResource(R.drawable.upper_left);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setOnTouchListener(this);

        /*RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);*/

        rootView.addView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                dX = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
                dY = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                v.animate()
                        .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                        .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start();
                //no use of ViewPositionUtil
                onMoveListener.onMove(new Position());//positionXY);
                break;
        }
        rootView.invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public void setOnMoveListener(OnMoveListener onMoveListener){
        this.onMoveListener = onMoveListener;
    }

    public float getCenterX(){
        return getX() + getWidth()  / 2;

    }
    public float getCenterY(){
        return getY() + getHeight() / 2;

    }

    public interface OnMoveListener{
        void onMove(Position positionXY);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The **ImageButton is Draggable** but it goes `outside of parent` .**Restrict** it to drag within it's parent Layout.

Comment: also tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662397/how-to-keep-an-image-within-layout-with-drag-and-drop

Comment: > Try this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974471/how-to-invoke-drag-event-of-a-custom-view-inside-surfaceview/53315898#53315898

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's an extract from my old diaries. Hope it works for you.

```
public class OnDragTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    /**
     * Callback used to indicate when the drag is finished
     */
    public interface OnDragActionListener {
        /**
         * Called when drag event is started
         *
         * @param view The view dragged
         */
        void onDragStart(View view);

        /**
         * Called when drag event is completed
         *
         * @param view The view dragged
         */
        void onDragEnd(View view);
    }

    private View mView;
    private View mParent;
    private boolean isDragging;
    private boolean isInitialized = false;

    private int width;
    private float xWhenAttached;
    private float maxLeft;
    private float maxRight;
    private float dX;

    private int height;
    private float yWhenAttached;
    private float maxTop;
    private float maxBottom;
    private float dY;

    private OnDragActionListener mOnDragActionListener;

    public OnDragTouchListener(View view) {
        this(view, (View) view.getParent(), null);
    }

    public OnDragTouchListener(View view, View parent) {
        this(view, parent, null);
    }

    public OnDragTouchListener(View view, OnDragActionListener onDragActionListener) {
        this(view, (View) view.getParent(), onDragActionListener);
    }

    public OnDragTouchListener(View view, View parent, OnDragActionListener onDragActionListener) {
        initListener(view, parent);
        setOnDragActionListener(onDragActionListener);
    }

    public void setOnDragActionListener(OnDragActionListener onDragActionListener) {
        mOnDragActionListener = onDragActionListener;
    }

    public void initListener(View view, View parent) {
        mView = view;
        mParent = parent;
        isDragging = false;
        isInitialized = false;
    }

    public void updateBounds() {
        updateViewBounds();
        updateParentBounds();
        isInitialized = true;
    }

    public void updateViewBounds() {
        width = mView.getWidth();
        xWhenAttached = mView.getX();
        dX = 0;

        height = mView.getHeight();
        yWhenAttached = mView.getY();
        dY = 0;
    }

    public void updateParentBounds() {
        maxLeft = 0;
        maxRight = maxLeft + mParent.getWidth();

        maxTop = 0;
        maxBottom = maxTop + mParent.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (isDragging) {
            float[] bounds = new float[4];
            // LEFT
            bounds[0] = event.getRawX() + dX;
            if (bounds[0] < maxLeft) {
                bounds[0] = maxLeft;
            }
            // RIGHT
            bounds[2] = bounds[0] + width;
            if (bounds[2] > maxRight) {
                bounds[2] = maxRight;
                bounds[0] = bounds[2] - width;
            }
            // TOP
            bounds[1] = event.getRawY() + dY;
            if (bounds[1] < maxTop) {
                bounds[1] = maxTop;
            }
            // BOTTOM
            bounds[3] = bounds[1] + height;
            if (bounds[3] > maxBottom) {
                bounds[3] = maxBottom;
                bounds[1] = bounds[3] - height;
            }

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    onDragFinish();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    mView.animate().x(bounds[0]).y(bounds[1]).setDuration(0).start();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    isDragging = true;
                    if (!isInitialized) {
                        updateBounds();
                    }
                    dX = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    dY = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    if (mOnDragActionListener != null) {
                        mOnDragActionListener.onDragStart(mView);
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void onDragFinish() {
        if (mOnDragActionListener != null) {
            mOnDragActionListener.onDragEnd(mView);
        }

        dX = 0;
        dY = 0;
        isDragging = false;
    }
}
```

And you can set it using:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnDragTouchListener(myView));
```

Or by adding this directly in `init` method of your Custom View:

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnDragTouchListener(this));
```

Comment: myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnDragTouchListener(myView,myParentView)) ; wroks thanks

Comment: Hi nice snippet...How to add onClickListener to the same view with same functionality?

Comment: @Rehan It worked just fine is there any way pinch to resize the view?

Comment: @SaiKiran Haven't tried resizing combination with drag functionality, you probably need to look into gesture detectors and combine with this code to provide both functionalities. [This](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale) might help.

Comment: @UsmanRana Obviously when you are intercepting touch event, it can affect the default behaviour of View. You need to modify the code if you want to achieve different end results.

Comment: yes, i've enable drag onLongClick instead of onTouchDown and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Great answer! However, once the view resizes suppose when it is clicked, the bounds get smaller than the full screen, any suggestion how to fix?

Comment: @RohitKumar Possibly because the parent of view is smaller than the full screen? Try sending different view to parent or try `view.getRootView()`, it might help

Comment: @RohitKumar Or you can also try calling `updateBounds()` after resize

Comment: Ok @Rehan, I will try out your solutions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey @Rehan, both your solutions didn't work for me sadly, could you suggest something else? The answer works great when the size of the view doesn't change!

Comment: @RohitKumar Not sure because ideally `updateBounds()` should update values after view resize. You can probably try debugging values if they are changed and assigned properly before and after resize.

Comment: @Rehan hmm, I will look into it. Thanks for replying so quickly!

Comment: @JawadZeb: I placed the code imageButtonCustom.setOnTouchListener(new OnDragTouchListener(imageButtonCustom,rootView)) ; on ImageButtonCustom init() but not working. Please suggest appropriate place to do so.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `rootView.getX()` and `rootView.getY()` as the left and top bounderies... and `(rootView.getX() + rootView.getWidth())` as the right and `(rootView.getY() + rootView.getHeight())` for the bottom boundary.

You have to write your boundary logic in onTouch() in the ACTION_MOVE case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In OnTouch you calculate where to move your view

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            v.animate()
                    .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                    .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                    .setDuration(0)
                    .start();
```

You should check the boundaries for x and y before moving it.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        float x = event.getRawX() + dX; float y = event.getRawY() + dY;
        if (x > boundaryRight) x = boundaryRight;
        else if (x < boundaryLeft) x = boundaryLeft;
        if (y < boundaryTop) y = boundaryTop;
        else if (y > boundaryBottom) y = boundaryBottom;
        v.animate()
                .x(x)
                .y(y)
                .setDuration(0)
                .start();
```

And to calculate boundaries of your RelativeLayout at run-time you should use Runnable or a Listener or similar [Determining the size of an Android view at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime)

Comment: how to get boundayParams inside ImageButtonCustom